# How do I check the status of apf firewall?

Tags: security, firewall

How to check whether apf (Advanced Policy Firewall) is running after the reboot? It doesn’t have any status, so how can we know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually APF logs somewhere (I believe /var/log/apf-log).  After rebooting your machine.  You can check the log.  If it is starting up properly you should see it loaded the rules during the time the machine was booting.

if chkconfig is installed run:

chkconfig --list apf

It should output something like:

apf             0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off

meaning that apf is set to start at run levels 2, 3, etc.

Your system probably boots into run level 3 by default.